# How does flutter_riverpod in Flutter convert ConsumerWidget to ConsumerStatefulWidget more conveniently?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am using [`flutter_riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package.

I want to convert `ConsumerWidget` to `ConsumerStatefulWidget`.

However, it took me a lot of time to do it like this:

1. (code)

```
class Widget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Widget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return …;
  }
}
```

2. (remove `ref`)

```
class Widget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Widget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return …;
  }
}
```

3. (change `ConsumerWidget` to `StatelessWidget`)

```
class Widget extends StatelessWidget {
  const Widget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return …;
  }
}
```

4. (converted by the `Convert to StatefulWidget` action)

```
class Widget extends StatefulWidget {
  const Widget({super.key});

  @override
  State<Widget> createState() => _WidgetState();
}

class _WidgetState extends State<Widget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return …;
  }
}
```

5. (add `Consumer` word)

```
class Widget extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Widget({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<Widget> createState() => _WidgetState();
}

class _WidgetState extends ConsumerState<Widget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return …;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I need to use 5 steps to do it. Is there a faster way?

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How to convert `ConsumerWidget` to `ConsumerStatefulWidget` more easily? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's often faster to just create a new ConsumerStatefulWidget and copy the code over. :)

Comment: Hi @RandalSchwartz thanks for your comment ok I will use your comment

Comment: Are you looking for a refactoring option? There's none at the moment, but I'll make one

Comment: Hi @RémiRousselet thanks for your comment. Yes, I'm looking for a refactoring option. Thanks, I'm looking forward to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my `ConsumerWidget` has no parameters,

- 1. Create a new `ConsumerStatefulWidget` with the same name.
- 2a. Copy content of `build` method of `ConsumerWidget` to a new created widget.
- 2b. (If there are other methods in the `ConsumerWidget`) Copy content of `ConsumerWidget` to a new created widget. Then remove `ref` from `build`.
- 3. Delete `ConsumerWidget`.

If my `ConsumerWidget` has parameters, then I'm doing the same as you, because otherwise I'll have to add a `widget.` before widget variables.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using [riverpod_lint](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_lint) package for your Riverpod projects. It auto converts your StatelessWidget to ConsumerWidget, etc. Also Riverpod extension for VSCode should be installed in your editor.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)